# Why NuGet restore task must be in the same job as the build task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget

In ***Azure DevOps*** when the ***NuGet restore*** task is run in the same **job** as the ***VS Build*** task everything is OK:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- job:
  steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: 'Framer/Framer.sln'

  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: 'Framer/Framer.sln'
      platform: 'Any CPU'
      configuration: 'Release'
```

But when they are in 2 different **job**s the VS Build fails:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- job:
  steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: 'Framer/Framer.sln'
- job:
  steps:
  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: 'Framer/Framer.sln'
      platform: 'Any CPU'
      configuration: 'Release'
```

With error:

```
Error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\Framer\FramerCLI\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

As if the restore task was not run.

What is the issue?
Is every job run in its own "context"?
But in the log I see that the root path `D:\a\1\s\` is exactly the same for both tasks, maybe there is some cleanup between the two?
Is there a way to run them in two jobs? (not sure this would be a good idea though)

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for jobs? It explains that jobs are independent. They can be run in parallel and by design do not share context. If you'd explain why you want to split them into different jobs, we can provide advice on achieving your goals within the design of Azure Pipelines.

Comment: This is a point I've missed.
I was mistaken by the fact I have only one agent and it operates in the same folder.
But I guess it cleans things up at the end of the first job or at the beginning of the second one.
It was merely a matter of organizing the tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the YAML you shared, we can see you are using the Microsoft-hosted `windows-latest` agent to run your pipeline jobs.

Based on the statement on the documention "[Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)":

> ***Each time you run a pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine for each job in the pipeline. The virtual machine is discarded after one job (which means any change that a job makes to the virtual machine file system, such as checking out code, will be unavailable to the next job).***

This means, every time you run pipeline jobs on the Microsoft-hosted agents, each job would get a fresh VM. In other words, each job could run on a different VM than other jobs, even if in the same pipeline run. Normally, after a job is finished, the VM for this job will be discarded. So, all the changes made by this job to the VM also will be discarded together with the VM.

So, you need to restore the packages in each job when running on the Microsoft-hosted agents.

If the packages every time you need to restore have a large size and are not updated often, you can consider using the [Cache task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cache-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to reduce time of restoring packages and improve build performance.

Comment: Thanks, indeed this is even more isolated than I thought!